# Web UI for Azure functions to monitor and replay queued items

Tags: azure, azure-functions, dashboard

I have been searching the web but I can't find a good solution for visualizing Azure function app queues.

I would like to be able to share a dashboard with a client showing them how their function is behaving, and possibly even allow them to replay queue items from the dead letter queue.

Does anybody know of any current solutions for this or do I need to custom build it?

Comment: By "app queues", do you mean Azure Storage Queues, or Azure Service Bus Message Queues? There is no OOTB tool for non-programmers to easily replay either types of messages. And if a message has been deadlettered, there is a good possibility that the underlying problem is with your program or with the message, and it's not as easy as re-submitting the same message to re-process it.

Comment: @RobReagan In my scenario its because the backend system was not available or went down for some reason. I was hoping for something like the Hangfire dashboard and I don't really care how the functions are triggered. Queues or Service Bus whatever I need to use. I'm still in design phase for my project and just need to make a decision on how to do this. Was hoping for some open source dashboard or something so I didn't need to develop it myself.